# How to include the Scrapy library in the Python runtime path

Tags: python-3.x, installation, scrapy

Python beginner here. I downloaded and installed latest version of Python on my Windows 7. I also downloaded the zip file for Scrapy. Now is it just a matter of putting the 'scrapy' folder in the 'Python' installation directory?

How will Python  pick up Scrapy? I come from Java background, and am used to putting the jar file under the 'lib' folder. Is it something similar

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [installation instructions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows)?

And if you [read the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-work-with-python-3) you would see that Scrapy works with Python 2.7 -- support for 3.x is work in progress.

If you install Scrapy the default way with `pip install scrapy` you would not need to care about the Path and the dependencies would be all installed too (something similar to Maven or Gradle but not exactly that).